# Parallax One Page site menubar

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Additional question about this site:
[mobiliteitsvisie](http://www.mobiliteitsvisie.nl)
When scrolling through the site, the menu-item should change with every slide it passes. At this moment the last clicked menu-item is highlighted, even when scrolling through to the several slides. Is there an easy way to make that work in CSS? Or would that only be possible by just adding a few lines in JavaScript or making a complete new jQuery.nav.js and adding a link into the index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be starting out, I'd recommend that you use a JavaScript plugin like `waypoints.js`.

This link has a good tutorial on it: http://www.oxygenna.com/tutorials/scroll-animations-using-waypoints-js-animate-css.

This has another tutorial on doing what you wanted to achieve: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints--webdesign-6408

Comment: thanks a lot! Indeed a starting developer, so every hint to useful tutorials is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this, add `data-scroll` to each nav anchors and `data-anchor` to each slide div ie

HTML:

```
       <a href="#" data-scroll=slide1>
       <a href="#" data-scroll=slide2>
        .
        .
        .
       <div id="slide1" data-anchor=slide1>
       <div id="slide2" data-anchor=slide2>
        .
        .
        .
```

SCRIPT:

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

           $("div[data-anchor^=slide]").each(function(i) {

                var currentArticle = $(this).attr('data-anchor');

                if ($(this).position().top <= scrollPos + 60 ) {
                  $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
                  $('#nav a[data-scroll="'+currentArticle+'"]').addClass("active");
                }

            });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tambo, I'll be sure try that later today!

Comment: Your are welcome if you need more help just comment.

Comment: Hey Kougi @Tambo, I'm sorry to say it didn't work out. I must've been placing the script in the wrong place I guess... But thanks anyway!